# Flex. pushView data Object being converted into a String

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flexbuilder

After executing a navigator.pushView with data object, I'm in need of the data object to be received into the next view, but at some stage transformed into a string to use in a sql function.
The code below shows what I'm working on at the moment.

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="{data.toString()}"
    xmlns:model="model.*"
    creationComplete  = "{data=srv.findByCategory(data.toString())}"
    >
```

.toString() was my quick attempt at it, but the resultant output is simply

> [object Object]

There aren't any errors but it only shows during debug.

Any ideas?

---

As appendage, here is the code from the initial view where the data object originates from

```
<s:List id="list" top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0" width="100%"
        alternatingItemColors="0xffffff"
        contentBackgroundColor="0xffffff"
        downColor="0xfc7d1a"
        selectionColor="0xfc7d1a"           
        dataProvider="{data}"
        labelFunction="getFullName"
        change="navigator.pushView(CategoryView, list.selectedItem.toString())">
```

And here is some of the code which needs the data object to be a String.

```
public function findByCategory(searchKey:String):ArrayCollection
        {
}
```

Comment: please post the complete code. Where is data binded ?

Comment: I've added some more code for background of it.

Answer (score 0):

data is a keyed object containing containing the info you passed from the initial view. You need to access the correct key in your object.

It should be something like `data.myKey.toString()`. I would be able to tell you exactly if you paste your pushView code.

Comment: ' <s:List id="list" top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0" width="100%"
   alternatingItemColors="0xffffff"
   contentBackgroundColor="0xffffff"
   downColor="0xfc7d1a"
   selectionColor="0xfc7d1a"   
   dataProvider="{data}"
   labelFunction="getFullName"
   change="navigator.pushView(CategoryView, list.selectedItem)">
'
Thanks for the answer, I'll look around as well. Let me know if this is or isn't what you were after.

Comment: @Pat so you would be able to access the data in this view the same way you do in your list